# Typescript- "property ip doesnt exist on type response"

Tags: typescript

Hello please can someone else with this typescript error, on this fetch api call I am getting on ip of userIp.ip "property ip doesnt exist on type response", here the code

```
`
      let userIp = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
      userIp = await userIp.json();
      data = await fetch(
        `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1? 
      apiKey=API_KEY&ipAddress=${userIp.ip}`
`
```

Answer (score 0):

##### First off: never put your private API keys in Stack Overflow questions (or any other online forums as well)!  I advise you reset your key as anyone can use them now.

You need to first get the data from the response in JSON before you can access properties off of this.  In your first request, you correctly used the `Response.json` method.  However, it seems you forgot to do this in your second which is the cause of your problem:

```
const userInfoRes = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
const userInfo = await userInfoRes.json();
const dataRes = await fetch(`https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=API_KEY&ipAddress=${userIp.ip}`);
const data = await dataRes.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you declare

`let userIp = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');`

`userIp` is of type `Response`.

Then with `userIp = await userIp.json();`, since `userIp.json()` returns a `Promise<any>`, it is the same as

`userIp: Response = await userIp.json();`

And it doesnt find the `ip` key in `Response`

Using another variable fixes it

```
  let userIp = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
  let userIpJson = await userIp.json();
  //You can also put a constraint
  //let userIpJson : { ip: string } = await userIp.json();
  console.log(userIpJson.ip)
```